How do valence band electrons move within a semiconductor lattice?
I am currently reading the book Semiconductor Device Fundamentals by Robert F. Pierret. In the chapter on carrier modeling, he discusses the valence and conductance energy bands of a semiconductor lattice of Silicon. From my understanding, electrons within the valence band are either tightly bound to the nucleus of the atom or are on the outer shell of the atom where they are known as valence electrons. Valence electrons form covalent bounds with the four nearest Si atom neighbors in the lattice. It is also my understanding that these valence electrons (in the valence band) with the absence of energy remain bonded and to be free to roam the crystal (or enter the conductance band) they must be excited with enough energy or the bandgap energy. However, counter to my knowledge and intuition the author describes the movement of valence electrons in the valence band as follows:

Unlike the valence electrons in the isolated-atom case, the band electrons in crystalline silicon are not tied to or associated with any one particular atom. True, on average, one will typically find four electrons being shared between any given Si atom and its four nearest neighbors. However, the identity of the shared electrons change as a function of time, with the electrons moving around from point to point in the crystal.

The author later in the text (the next page) further explains this movement as movement in the valence band, he states the following:

As accurately portrayed in the the energy band model, however, the valence band electrons actually move about in the crystal. How is it then that no current can arise from this group of electrons? As it turns out, the momentum of the electrons is quantized in addition to their energy. Moreover, for each and every possible momentum state in a band, there is another state with an oppositely directed momentum of equal magnitude. Thus, if a band is completely filled with electrons the net momentum of the electrons in the band is always identically zero. It follows that no current can arise from the electrons in a completely filled energy band.

My questions regarding these block quotes are as follows:

How are valence band electrons moving about in the crystal, I thought to break the covalent bond they need energy equal to the bandgap energy and thus they would be in the conductance band?

The author describes momentum states of electrons - is he referring to the orbital angular momentum quantum number? If so, how does the shape of the electron's orbital affect current when they are moving about in the crystal? Or is he referring to the linear momentum (mass * velocity) of a moving particle and how does that affect the current?



intrinsic or doped semiconductror?

@RootGroves Intrinsic semiconductor.

On average due to temperature some of the electrons in the valence band move to the conduction band so they can move freely.
Note that you dont need electrons in the conduction band to have a electric current,you can have current by motion of charge carriers in the valence band,
generally you need unfullfilled energy states.

This doesn't really answer OP's question.

@HiddenBabel ehmm hello?I just did?If you know how I should improve my answer please load it up,otherwise shush.Anyway your comment is pointless because it does really add something in the answers.

Forget all the molecular bonding stuff and four electrons to an atom. The bonding is across the whole solid.
Electrons are in Bloch states in periodic solids; they are traveling plane waves.
The author is not referring to orbital angular momentum. He is referring to crystal momentum, which is the momentum (or wave vector) you find in the argument of the plane waves.
